# Laptops thats support Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, laptop

I am looking for laptops which supports Windows XP.

I am a programmer who mainly works on developing websites.Suggest me laptop models which have best drivers support for XP

Please forgive me if you consider my question silly or below standard. I am unable to find the laptop models that support XP in internet so I am posting in stack.

Thanks for reply

Comment: Technically all laptops support XP. The problem is to find drivers for the components...

Comment: Shopping/recommendation questions are off topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a non-answer, but still.

If you just want to test websites on XP, I suggest to just use virtual machine and not buy a complete laptop.

A nice guide for XP virtual machines is here

http://www.technibble.com/how-to-create-a-windows-xp-virtual-machine/

Comment: Thanks for Reply Karel.To test website I need only browser.OS is no concern to me